# Does kmeans.transform return the euclidian distance of each point to its assigned cluster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, k-means

I have the following dataset to which i fit a kmeans with `k=3`

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# Generate some random clusters
X, y = make_blobs()
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(X)
```

I am calculating the distance of each point to each assigned cluster by [using](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.transform) `kmeans.transform(X)`

```
# squared distance to cluster center
X_dist = kmeans.transform(X)**2

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(X_dist.sum(axis=1).round(2), columns=['sqdist'])
df['label'] = y

df.head()
```

and I get this

```
sqdist  label
0   200.04  1
1   303.11  0
2   267.50  0
3   181.64  1
4   334.58  2
```

Now if I want to calculate this distance "manually", I will do this

```
X_dt = pd.DataFrame(X)
X_dt['cluster'] = y
for k, centroid in enumerate(kmeans.cluster_centers_):
    
    d = np.linalg.norm(X - centroid, axis=1)
    X_dt[f'cluster_distance_{k}'] = d
```

And this will give me this

```
X_dt.head()

0   1   cluster cluster_distance_0  cluster_distance_1  cluster_distance_2
0   3.445588    2.479573    1   0.523083    9.900408    10.086907
1   6.942484    -7.084589   0   9.992428    14.212855   1.119853
2   5.673418    -7.160752   0   9.765687    13.117708   0.233798
3   4.000135    1.330473    1   1.124870    10.108471   8.842795
4   -6.925704   -1.042616   2   11.441470   1.076678    14.230793
```

There are two things that we notice if we look at the final `X_dt`:

1. The datapoint, is not assigned to the centroid that is "closest" to it
2. The distance in when computed the manual way, is not aligned with the "distance" when calculated using `kmeans.transform`

Any ideas why do these 2 things happen ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To each of the question:

1. The label y you have here is pre-generated by make_blobs(), not the predicted cluster of KMean. As make_blobs() is generated by gaussian, the label is the Gaussian center of each data points, not necessarily the closest center. To get the predicted cluster of KMean, use the following:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(X)
kmeans.labels_
```

2. What kmeans.transform(X) returns is already the L2 norm distance to each cluster center, there is no need to compute it again. You can compare it with the returned values of np.linalg.norm().